# Angular2 router parameter which includes a semicolon

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, router

I'm using Angular2 and the RouterModule. I have a child state which is waiting for a parameter (id):

```
{
   path: 'details/:id',
   component: DetailComponent,
   outlet: 'details'
}
```

In my case, the parameter id could include semicolons (i.e: TEST|EN;1000;0).

I'm using the activated route to get the params `let taskIdFromParam = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.params['id'];` But as a result i'm getting `TEST|EN` instead of **TEST|EN;1000;0**

The rest of the id us included in the urlSegment as parameters (`Object {0: "", 1000: "", EN: ""}`). I have tried parsing the rest of the parameters and joining it manually with a semicolon, but they are in alphabetic order so the id that I parse is **TEST|0;1000;EN** instead of **TEST|EN;1000;0**.

I know that this is happening because the angular router uses Matrix URL notation for child states (see following [link](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#optionally-selecting)).

I have the following questions:

1. Is there a way to use **QueryParameters** on a child state?
2. Is there a way to tell the Router to not escape the semicolon?

Comment: I would just change the way it is designed and use a technical, autogenerated ID, without any special character, to identify the resource instead of that ugly string. And if that's really not possible, transform this functional information to base64-url or hexadecimal to get an ID containing no special character. Using query params is a workaround, that doesn't scale well: what if you have a multi-level path with 2 or 3 ids?

Comment: Which angular2 version are you using?

Comment: @TheDictator 4.0.1

Answer (score 0):

1. yes you can use query params
2. query params will encode special characters

http://yoururl.com/state?yourParam=TEST|EN;1000;0

```
this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
  console.log(params['yourParam']);
});
```